# Implementing Neural network to student attendance system

Tags: java, neural-network

i am about to start my final project, its developing  system that will predict a student attendance base on the past attendance he had. so i am a newbie to programming but i desperate to begin learning JAVA and also applying Neural Network to accomplish my objectives. so i was hoping you could assist me with guidelines on where to start, and don't forget, i only have 9 months left. and also provide me with suggestions and tutorials...pls

Comment: does it have to use a Neural Network algorithm? Perhaps Bayes might be appropriate?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is far too broad to answer. You should go do several things: A) go learn to program in Java, B) go learn what a neural network is, C) learn how to implement a neural network, and THEN come back and ask how to apply your knowledge to the problem at hand. This is a lot to do in 9 months, so start now!

Answer (score 2):

1. Why Java?  Look into Python (It will be easier to pick up if you are new to programming).
2. Regardless you are going to need to devote a good bit of time to learning programing.  Your question sounds like "I going on a sailing trip but I need to build a sailboat and I am new to carpentry, are there any good tutorials".
3. Make sure you work out algorithms on paper before you start coding.

Answer (score 1):

... after learning Java you should look for some good API for neural networks. I suggest [Encog](http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog)
for this.